Deployment of a GitHub Page using Astro fails to install build and upload due to action configuration
I'm following this tutorial
The issue :
The fail happens at "Install build, and upload your site". The issue says as follows :

>Run withastro/action@v3
\>Run len=`echo $INPUT_PM | wc -c`
No lockfile found.
Please specify your preferred "package-manager" in the action configuration.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

I am a total beginer on Astro and web pages. I want to make a simple github page with astro, I would just like to create a working main page for now.
My github repo is available here and only contains 2 files : the deploy and the config
What I did first:
All the code I use is from the tutorial linked above.
I created an astro.config.mjs file as said in the tutorial. I tried removing the base line as I set an empty base name but it also leads to failure. Here is the code :
import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config'

export default defineConfig({
  site: 'https://lafitteque.github.io',
  base: '',
})

I created the workflow like in the tutorial. I put it inside .github/workflows/ and named it deploy.yml here is the code :
name: Deploy to GitHub Pages

on:
  # Trigger the workflow every time you push to the `main` branch
  # Using a different branch name? Replace `main` with your branch’s name
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab on GitHub.
  workflow_dispatch:

# Allow this job to clone the repo and create a page deployment
permissions:
  contents: read
  pages: write
  id-token: write

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout your repository using git
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Install, build, and upload your site
        uses: withastro/action@v3
        # with:
          # path: . # The root location of your Astro project inside the repository. (optional)
          # node-version: 20 # The specific version of Node that should be used to build your site. Defaults to 20. (optional)
          # package-manager: pnpm@latest # The Node package manager that should be used to install dependencies and build your site. Automatically detected based on your lockfile. (optional)

  deploy:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment:
      name: github-pages
      url: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.page_url }}
    steps:
      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        id: deployment
        uses: actions/deploy-pages@v4

What I tried:
I tried selecting the optional manager (the one commented by default in the deploy.yaml) but it just leads to more fails.

See Caution under Configure a GitHub Action section.

It says : "Don’t set a base parameter if Your page is served from the root folder" which is the case if I understand correctly. I tried an empty string but also no base item in the mjs. None worked

You need to commit the lock file too.
